# Clear hidden value when navigating table rows using hover timeout

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Hello guys just need a little help here. I hope you can help me.
Here's the scenario:

1. In my category table there's a lot of rows. Every row has a hidden textbox with an empty value and a unique id. When the user navigates, the comments for that category will display below together with the comment form for that.
2. If the user hovers in a specific category/rows for three(3) seconds the hidden value will get the id of the category and assign it to my hidden textbox. If the user didn't stay hovered for at least 3 seconds in a row, nothing will happen.
3. After that if the user hovered over another row for 3 seconds the previous hidden text value should be clear and assign a new value for the hovered row.

My problem is, when I navigate the rows and stay hovered for three seconds I can get the correct hidden value. But when I go to another row I can also get the correct hidden values but the previous hidden didn't clear or reset. How can I do that?

Here's my code, I hope you understand my point guys.  Thanks.

```
<?php
foreach($queryViewEntries as $row){

    $temp_id = $row['salescatid'];
    $cat_id = $row['salescatid'];

    echo '<tr>'
        .'<td width="5%" style="text-align: center">'
            .'<input type="text" name="indicator" value="" class="indicator" id="indicator'.$temp_id.'" style="width: 16px" />'
            .'&nbsp;'
            .'<input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="'.$row['salescatid'].'" id="check'.$row['salescatid'].'" onclick="check(this)" id="comment'.$row['salescatid'].'" />'
         .'</td>'
        .'<td width="10%">{'.$row['salescatname'].'}</td>'
        .'<td class="hover_comment">'
            .'<span style="display: none;">{'.$row['salescatid'].'}</span>'
            .'{'.$row['salescatdesc'].'}'
        .'</td>'
        .'<td width="30%" style="text-align: center;" class="hover_comment">'
            .'<a href="#" class="buttons edit" data-value="'.$cat_id.'" name="edit_item">EDIT</a>'
            .'<a href="#" class="buttons delete" data-value="'.$cat_id.'" name="delete_item">DELETE</a>'
        .'</td>'
    .'</tr>';
}
//HERE I SET THE HIDDEN TO A SIMPLE TEXTBOX(named 'indicator') SO THAT I CAN SEE THE VALUE INSIDE  
?>

//BELOW IS MY JQUERY CODE
$(function(){

    var counter = 0,
        myInterval = null,
        temp = null,
        salesid = null;

    $(".hover_comment").hover(function(e){

        counter = 0;

        myInterval = setInterval(function(){
            ++counter;
            console.log(counter);
        }, 1000);

        salesid = $(this).find('span').text();
        $(".comment_boxes").hide();
        setTimeout(function(){$(".comment_box_"+salesid).fadeIn()}); 

        $('#txt_id').val(salesid);
        $(this).find(".tempid").val();
        $("#comment_add").show(); 

    },function(e){

        clearInterval(myInterval);

        if(counter > 3){
            $("#indicator").val('');
            alert(counter);
            //alert(salesid);
            $("#indicator"+salesid).val(salesid);
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: are you trying to post new html over the html already inside the row titled 'hidden'?

Comment: I'm trying to insert a value in my hidden box if the user hovered a specific row for 3 seconds. And if the user hovered again the previous hidden data will not cleared as soon as the user hovered another hidden box for 3 seconds.

Comment: @user2585508 You have a `setTimeout` (`setTimeout(function(){$(".comment_box_"+salesid).fadeIn()});`) with no delay!

Comment: What do you mean about settimeout? Do i need to include how many seconds before timeout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [JQuery wildcard `^` selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) to clear all the `#indicator` elements:

```
$("[id^=indicator]").val('');
```

The caret `^` means to select all rows that have an ID starting with "indicator".